# How to remove output 'None' when iterator is called?

Tags: python, iterator

Well, I wrote an iterator Divisors(n) that gets a natural number n as its argument and generates divisors of n (from the smallest to the largest). Here's code:

```
class Divisors:

    def __init__(self, n):
        self.n = n
        self.i = 0

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        self.i += 1
        if self.i == self.n + 1:
            raise StopIteration
        if self.n % self.i == 0:
            return self.i
```

But, when I run it, I get:

```
>>> print([x for x in Divisors(12)])
[1, 2, 3, 4, None, 6, None, None, None, None, None, 12]
```

Question is: How to remove these `None`'s from list to obtain:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 12]
```

Yes, I know this can be done like this:

```
def divisors(n):
    i = 1
    while i <= n:
        if n % i == 0:
            yield i
        i += 1
```

but I am interested in way I mentioned above.

Comment: When your object is asked for its next value, and it doesn’t happen to raise a `StopIteration` and it’s also not a divisible value, then you’re not returning anything. You must increment `i` until you found the “next” value and always return a value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could keep incrementing `self.i` till it evenly divides the `self.n`:

```
class Divisors:
    def __init__(self, n):
        self.n = n
        self.i = 0

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        self.i += 1
        if self.i == self.n + 1:
            raise StopIteration

        # Keep incrementing
        while self.n % self.i != 0:
            self.i += 1

        # Now it is guaranteed to divide
        return self.i
```

Answer (score 1):

I suspect this might work:

```
    def __next__(self):
        self.i += 1
        if self.i == self.n + 1:
            raise StopIteration
        if self.n % self.i == 0:
            return self.i
        else
            return self.__next__()
```

Some perfer the following style which should have a similar effect.

```
    def __next__(self):
        self.i += 1
        if self.i == self.n + 1:
            raise StopIteration
        if self.n % self.i == 0:
            return self.i

        return self.__next__()
```